# MVC 5 Html.BeginForm without model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple search form on my _Layout page.

How can I easily pass the value from search-fld to the controller? Without having to create a Model or ViewModel.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", new { id = "search-fld" }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "header-search pull-right" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="search-fld">
    <button type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
}
```

If I run this then "search-fld" get send to the controller (offcourse)

Use Ajax form instead and get the value with Jquery?

Answer (score 15):

Simply by giving your `input` a `name` attribute:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="search-fld" name="searchValue">
```

Then matching that name with a parameter in your controller `HttpPost` method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string searchValue)
```

Comment: Yea, that kind of works. The only problem is that the URL now is http://localhost:52223/ and if i search for "asd" it passes the parameter and the URL changes to http://localhost:52223/Search but I want it to say http://localhost:52223/Search/asd and this works if I have a Custom route on the controller like this: [Route("Search/{searchString}")] BUT then it doesn't work since it doesnt pass the value in route attributes from the form :/ Any suggestions?

Comment: Also have custom route mapped in Route.Config. Like this:       routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Home",
          url: "{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

Comment: If the names match up it will, i.e. if you have `public ActionResult Search(string searchValue)`, then you also need `name="searchValue"` on your input and `[Route("Search/{searchValue}")]` as your route.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Ajax call like that :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#yourButton").click(function () {
            var yourValue = $("#search-fld").val() ;
            var url = "Search/asd/";
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    searchValue = yourValue
                }
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data === true) {
                        alert('Success');
                    } else {
                        alert('Failed');
                    }
                    }
                })
            })
        })
```

And Your Method in controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult asd(string searchValue)
{

}
```